# API Management Development Portal is not using the latest AAD B2C identity config settings after updating in the Identities blade

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-api-management

I have an APIM instance that was set up initially to use a built in user flow in B2C. The settings look like so:

[image: Initial APIM B2C Identity Settings]

When I update the sign-up policy and the sign-in policy to a new custom policy from B2C, the sign in page continues to use the old config settings.

[image: New APIM B2C Identity Settings]

When I go to the sign in page, the developer portal is pulling down a JSON file from `/config-apim.json` which returns the old settings. Although the settings come back as a new, something changes internally somewhere that when logging in portal returns an "invalid token" error.

It is almost as it is internally using the new policy but then the developer portal is using the old token settings.

[image: apim-config.json]

What has been tried:

- Updating these settings
- Removing the identity provider completely and readding
- Removing any references to the old flow in any setting (could not find anything)
- Assuming it was cached somewhere, updated to the new settings and waited a few hours to see if it would magically use the new settings.

Comment: You can refer to similar issues on GitHub: https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/issues/1452 , https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/issues/1661 and https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/issues/1686 . You can also open a new issue: https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/issues

Comment: Thanks for the links. I feared it was a bug in the developer portal but wanted to be sure by asking here first. I'll go ahead and open a new issue on their repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you need to re-publish portal to apply this change.

Comment: Republishing the portal fixed it. Thanks. Oddly, I didn't see that mentioned anywhere though that it would need republished upon updating the identity settings and I looked nearly everywhere.